# How to Get User-Generated Columns from Ajax

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, rest, filter, ajax

Is it possible to determine which columns in a SP List or document library were custom generated by the user? I'm essentially trying to recreate SharePoint's front end in my app, and I want to add columns to my table just like if the user adds a column in SP. My issue is determining which columns are non-standard.

I already know how to get properties for list items/files and I can see my user generated columns in the response. I'm just looking for **is there a way to filter only non-standard columns?**

**User Generated Column in SP**

[image]

**Field Display in Results (as well as all other default fields)**

[image]